# How does heat transfer depend on fluid viscosity

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, transport-phenomena

I’ve been dealing with a forced convection internal flow (regular vertical pipe) system where viscosity grows significantly through time.

The flow is way within laminar region, and I want to predict how the viscosity increase affects the heat transfer coefficient h on the wall, which is kept at a constant temperature. Flow velocity is kept constant too.

Looking at the models in the literature, either a constant Nusselt number of 3,66 is used (fully developed flow) or correlations that are functions of the peclet number. The peclet number however is not a function of the viscosity.

In my head a much higher viscosity would affect the heat transfer negatively but that doesn’t seem to be the case. Am I correct to assume that for laminar flow in pipes the Nusselt number and hence the heat transfer coefficient is independent of the viscosity? If not, how does viscosity affect it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The heat transfer descriptions you are referring to were derived assuming that the axial velocity profile is the same as that for isothermal flow.  It also assumes that viscous heating is negligible.  Under these circumstances, viscosity is not a parameter.  But, if the viscosity varies with radial position in the tube, the heat transfer coefficient will be affected.  Lower viscosity near the wall than in the bulk will result in higher shear rates near the wall, thinner thermal boundary layers, and higher heat transfer coefficients.  The opposite with prevail if the viscosity is higher near the wall.

Purely axial variation of viscosity would not be expected to have much of an effect.